# Random Name Picker

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class which contains 10 names (U1, U2, U3..and so on). I have to choose 5 names everyday, and display one as the Editor and 4 as Contributors

While selecting the random names, I have to also consider that if one user is selected as Editor, he cannot become editor again till everyone got their chance.

The output should look similar to the following:

```
           Editor   Cont1   Cont2     Cont3    Cont4
20-Jun   U1      U8       U9         U3       U4
21-Jun    U7      U2       U5         U6       U10
22-Jun    U3      U4       U9         U2       U8
23-Jun      U4      U8       U3          U5      U2
and so on..
```

Can I do this in LINQ?

Comment: Yes. You could more than likely do this using LINQ. Possibly not in a single statement. If you would like to know how, I suggest you propose how/where you'll be storing your domain model - e.g. Are "assignments" (editor/contributor) stored next to a "person"?

Comment: I won't really store the records..assume a List<Person> with a single column called Name..I just want to generate the output with the given conditions..possible?

Comment: Would it be better to have the Editors in a fixed, repeating order (e.g. U1, U2, U3, U4, U5, U6, U7, U8, U9, U10, U1, U2, etc) and pick contributors randomly? You could pick Editors randomly in blocks of 10 but then you could have the case where the first Editor to be picked was the same as the last one from the previous block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use Linq, but instead use the Random class provided by the .Net Framework.

```
Random random = new Random();
List<Person> tmpList = new List<Person>(personList);
int item = random.Next(tmpList.Count);
Person editor = tmpList[item];
tmpList.RemoveAt(item);
List<Person> contributors = new List<Person>();
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
     item = random.Next(tmpList.Count);
     contributors.Add(tmpList[item]);
     tmpList.RemoveAt(item);
}
```